# Run single Kotlin file

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have two Kotlin files in the same folder:

[image]

Both files have a trivial main method.
I can right click on helloworld.kt file and select "Run..." from the menu.
There's no such option for the circle.kt file though.

This is my run/debug configuration for helloworld.kt:
[image]

I tried to create an equivalent configuration for circle.kt, but it complains that the class com.example.kotlin.learning.CircleKt has no main method:

[image]

There's actually no class in that file. But there isn't one in HelloWorld.kt as well, and that works.

Here's the code for helloworld.kt:

```
package com.example.kotlin.learing


fun main (argomenti: Array<String>) {
    println ("SUCA!")
    println (saluta ( "mario"))

    val vettore : Array<String> = arrayOf("pippo", "pluto", "paperino")
    println(vettore [0])
}

fun saluta (chi : String) = ( chi + " antani" )
```

here's circle.kt:

```
package com.example.kotlin.learing



fun main() = println("pippuz!")
```

I realize I am missing something deep here. What is that?
Thanks

Comment: Please show how exactly the main method in circle.kt is declared.

Comment: Impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing the actual code. When i make 2 classes in same package, with main functions, i can run both just fine.

Comment: Added the code of both files. Thanks.

Comment: Try with the following signature instead: `fun main(vararg args: String)`

Comment: Also note that you can just right-click in the main function declaration and select Run, this will automatically create the proper run configuration for you.

Comment: @m0skit0 that's just a syntactic equivalent to what he is using. Both work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `main` method without parameters is supported from [Kotlin version 1.3-RC](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/09/kotlin-1-3-rc-is-here-migrate-your-coroutines/). Which version of Kotlin are you using?

If you are using an older version of Kotlin, you should pass an array of Strings as the argument of the `main` method.

Comment: this worked. That's silly, because the file compiled with no errors anyways.

Comment: It's not an error to declare a function with any name or signature, so there is no reason why the file wouldn't compile.

Comment: LOL. Now it's not working any longer. It appears to be a quite random behavior.